# How to free memory in Mac OS X?

Tags: memory, osx-leopard

I have Macbook Pro running Mac OS X Leopard (10.5) with 4GB RAM. I use some applications (Parallels for Windows (1GB RAM), Firefox, mail, freemind, iTunes, Finder, Terminal and that's it), and I can observe that after some time memory is completely full and system's performance decreases. I wonder

1. how can I know the real use of my programs in memory? I use activity monitor but if I add up all the individual contributions I never get 4GB RAM.
2. if there are some services that are wasting memory and which I do not need like google update etc, and how can I deactivate them?
3. is there other advices for freeing memory?

Comment: Well, this isn't apple specific advice, so I'm not sure that it will work well, but try with `top` command in terminal or with `cat /proc/meminfo`. Those two should be able to show memory status. Hopefully, someone will be able to give you OS X specific advice soon.

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/244553/mac-os-x-what-is-using-my-active-memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I know the real use of my programs in memory. I use activity monitor but if I add up all the individual contributions I never get 4GB RAM

It is a good thing that you never get 4GB RAM. It would be very bad for your system if all your applications used **all** your real memory. There must be some free memory at all times for the system to run smoothly and virtual memory paging to work properly. I would be worried if your free memory is under 50 MB.

Apple has a [support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1342) explaining memory usage shown in Activity Monitor.

I like [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) for giving me a quick snapshot of my memory/CPU/Network usage.

> if there are some services that are wasting memory and which I do not need like google update, etc, and how can I deactivate them

You can see what processes are using a lot of memory with Activity Monitor and quit processes there.

Unless your *Page outs* value under the System Memory tab is very high compared to the *Page ins* value, or you get excessive disk thrashing, I wouldn't worry about it. I think the best way to limit memory usage, given the set of applications you are using, is simply to keep the number of tabs/windows you have open in Firefox to a minimum. 4 GB should be more than enough to run that set of applications in Mac OS X.

> other advices for freeing memory

Frankly, in my opinion there's not much you can do besides limiting the number of applications/startup items you launch.

The most important thing is ensuring you have enough disk space for Virtual Memory paging. The X Lab has an [excellent article](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/lackofram.html) explaining memory usage and how to determine if you have sufficient memory.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to question 3: Use the **purge** command in a terminal to forcefully free some disk caches from memory. It will increase the amount of "Free" memory available.

Man page:

> purge(8)                  BSD System Manager's Manual
>
> NAME
>        purge -- force disk cache to be purged (flushed and emptied)
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        purge
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        Purge can be used to approximate initial boot conditions with a
>   cold disk buffer cache for performance analy-
>        sis. It does not affect anonymous memory that has been allocated
>   through malloc, vm_allocate, etc.
>
> SEE ALSO
>        sync(8), malloc(3)